# How to add webform login to an nginx basic auth website?

Tags: nginx, basic-authentication

I have a simple nginx static site with basic auth. When someone wants to access the site, they get the browser modal dialog prompting for username/password:

nginx.conf:

```
server {
  listen 1337;
  server_name _;
  root /app/public;
  location / {
    auth_basic "Protected";
    auth_basic_user_file /app/etc/htpasswd;
  }
}
```

How can change it so that instead of a dialog I end up with a web form to enter username and password against the same `htpasswd` file?

I tried adding the following to `nginx.conf`:

```
# In location / block
error_page 401 =418 /login/?dest=https://$http_host$request_uri;

# In server block
location /login/ {
  auth_basic off;
}
```

Return code `418` to kill the popup and I like teapots. 
In `/app/public/login/` I created `index.html` that has a simple form:

```html
<script>
function authenticate() {
  var login = document.getElementById('username').value;
  var pass = document.getElementById('password').value;
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.withCredentials = true;
  xhr.open("GET", "/", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Basic ' + btoa(login + ':' + pass));
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log('xhr ready state: ' + xhr.readyState);
    console.log('xhr status: ' + xhr.status);
    console.log('xhr response: ' + xhr.response);
  };
  xhr.send();
}
</script>
<form method="get" onsubmit="authenticate(); return false">
    <input type="text" id="username" autocomplete="username" required/>
    <input type="password" id="password" autocomplete="current-password" required/>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
</form>
```

I tried an AJAX/XHR to the original destination url to see if it returned a 200 (login successful) or 418 (login fail) but I can't figure out how to set the Authorization header on all subsequent requests or if it's possible. Any help / suggestions appreciated.